# Multi-Tenancy (Multi-user) GPU Container Infrastructure Solution

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, cuda, operations-orchestration

**What we need:** Several teams from different companies want to share our GPUs for deep learning tasks (three computers with several GPUs each). So manage multiple GPUs for multiple users.

- Different teams should not have access to the data of other teams.
- Teams itsself should be able to run whatever container they need (with GPU, e.g. tensorflow, etc.)
- Each team should have at least 8 GPUs and a maxmimum of e.g. 15 GPUs, so GPUs are used most of the time
- Stats about GPU usage would be good to see who is not using them.
- Access of several containers to same datasets (per team) to train on
- Teams should not be able to escape the container, e..g mount '/' from the host to the docker container and delete / remove / edit random files on server which would lead to data breach.

**Question:** *What are the best open source tools to achieve this?*

e.g. something like Rancher 2.0? Mesosphere? How should we set up storage? NFS? How does Uber? Google? Other DL startups do that?

**Similar unanswered questions:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547889/managing-multiple-gpus-with-multiple-users
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201399/docker-server-for-multiple-users

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. Potentially your question can be reworded or made suitable for the  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange community, but before posting, please read their guidelines. Alternatively Wikipedia often has lists of available products.

Comment: If this seems to be off-topic, where can I ask this or post this question? What are suited sites for this type of question?